# Python Code-complete System

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm working on a Python Autocomplete/Code-complete system. I'm already able to parse my own source files with `import ast` to access my own defined classes + functions.

Now I'd like to know, how to access the signatures of system-classes, functions, constants etc..

How am I able to access this information? Is it also possible with python's `ast` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`inspect.getargspec(func)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec)

> Get the names and default values of a Python function’s arguments. A
>   tuple of four things is returned: `(args, varargs, keywords, defaults)`.
>   *args* is a list of the argument names (it may contain nested lists).
>   *varargs* and *keywords* are the names of the `*` and `**` arguments or None.
>   *defaults* is a tuple of default argument values or None if there are no
>   default arguments; if this tuple has *n* elements, they correspond to
>   the last *n* elements listed in *args*.
>
> *Changed in version 2.6*: Returns a *named tuple* `ArgSpec(args, varargs,
>   keywords, defaults)`.

This will only work for actual functions written in Python; other callables, such as types or built-in functions, won't be compatible.